# Socket communication between Pi and Arduino

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, arduino, sockets

I'm a beginner with Raspi and I would appreciate your advice and input on a project I'm working on.

Hardware: Raspi 3B+ with latest Rasbian, Arduino MKR 1000

I have a bunch of sensors attached to the Raspi(Ultrasonic and IMU) and I want to pass data from the Raspi to the MKR1000 with Raspi acting like  server and Arduino like a client. They will be connected to the same network through Wi-Fi.  I want to know if this is possible and what is the most easiest way to do this? Also, I was advised that writing a socket would be helpful with the problem but I have no clue how to write a socket for Arduino that can interact with the Pi, I already have a socket server program that I use for Pi(Code below), would this program be capable of sending strings to the Arduino? Any resources, videos, sample code would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
import socket
import sys

    HOST = '192.168.130.206'    #Ip the server is run on
    PORT = 50007              # Arbitrary non-privileged port
    s = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except OSError as msg:
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.bind(sa)
            s.listen(1)
        except OSError as msg:
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print('could not open socket')
        sys.exit(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data: break
            conn.send(data)
    enter code here
```

Comment: Ask Arduino questions on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: But the question is focused on Raspi as well though? I dont know if the Pi is capable of acting like a server and if it is possible for the Pi to communicate with the Arduino through sockets. Should this be a Arduino question instead?